# How to save the dynamic data as pdf or excel?

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, pageblocktable, pagereference, data-export

Here in my page, I select some picklist field values and based on that i will get the data, Then, When i click the "ExportReport" button,Then data need to save as excel or pdf. I know with pageReference we can do, I gave pageRefrence for "ExportReport" button to save as pdf, But How to give this table in pagreReference page? or can we do in another way?

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="ReportPageCon">
<apex:form >
              <apex:actionFunction name="dosearchaction" action="{!dosearch}" reRender="showId"/><br/>

  <apex:pageblock title="Report:">
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select the Location:">
         <apex:selectList id="pick1" value="{!picklistval1}" size="1" required="true">    
               <apex:outputLabel for="pick1"><b>District:</b></apex:outputLabel>&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <apex:selectOptions value="{!value1}"/>
          </apex:selectList>

          <apex:selectList id="pick2" value="{!picklistval2}" size="1" required="true">
                         <apex:outputLabel for="pick1"><b>Mandal:</b></apex:outputLabel>&nbsp;&nbsp;

              <apex:selectOptions value="{!value2}"/>
          </apex:selectList>
                    <apex:selectList id="pick3" value="{!picklistval3}" size="1" required="true">
                                   <apex:outputLabel for="pick1"><b>Village:</b></apex:outputLabel>&nbsp;&nbsp;

              <apex:selectOptions value="{!value3}"/>
          </apex:selectList>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="showId">
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objList}" var="item">
              <apex:column value="{!item.State__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.District__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Mandal__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Village__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.First_Name__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!item.Aadhar_ID__c}"/>
                                          <apex:column value="{!item.Gender__c}"/>
                                          <apex:column value="{!item.Date_Of_Birth__c}"/>
                            </apex:pageblockTable>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:commandButton value="Generate Report" action="{!dosearch}" onclick="dosearchaction();" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <apex:commandButton value="Export Report" action="{!ExportReport}"/>
  </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class ReportPageCon {

public String picklistval1 {get;set;}
public String picklistval2 {get;set;}
public String picklistval3 {get;set;}
public List<object__c> objList{get;set;}

public ReportPageCon() {
    objList=new List<object__c>();
}

public List<SelectOption> getvalue1(){

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = object__c.District__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
      options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }       
    return options;
}

public List<SelectOption> getvalue2(){

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = object__c.mandal__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
      options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }       
    return options;
}
    public List<SelectOption> getvalue3(){

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = object__c.Village__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
    {
      options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }       
    return options;
}
public void dosearch(){
    objList = [Select First_Name__c,Mobile_Number__c,Gender__c , Name,state__c,District__c,mandal__c,Age__c,Village__c from object__c Where District__c =: picklistval1 and mandal__c=:picklistval2 and village__c=:picklistval3]; //change according to your criteria

}
    public pageReference ExportReport()
    {

        PageReference myVFPage = new PageReference('/apex/ExportReportPage');

    return myVFPage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Ape page class and pages are perfect, just need to add little more .please follow the below step : -

1. In your **ExportReportPage** by using the same controller just built the same pageblock table like below : -

   ```
   `<apex:page controller="ReportPageCon" id="MainPage" showHeader="false" cache="true" contentType="application/x-pdf#Here-is-your-filename.pdf"`>  
   <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objList}" var="item">
       <apex:column value="{!item.State__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!item.District__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!item.Mandal__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!item.Village__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!item.First_Name__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!item.Aadhar_ID__c}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!item.Gender__c}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!item.Date_Of_Birth__c}"/>
       </apex:pageblockTable>          
   </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>                
    </apex:page>
   ```

As you are using same controller you can use the **objList** list which is already being populated in first page.

In the second page you can use **contentType="application/x-pdf#Here-is-your-filename.pdf"** ,so whenever the second page gets loaded it will download as PDF.

If you want to download as word then do the below changes in **contentType**, like **contentType="application/msWord#yourFile.doc"**

Comment: Thank you, ur code is working fine. It is saving as Exel but it is not saving as pdf. I have tried from developer docs also. but not getting. Can you help on this.   I am getting error with above content type: Failed to load PDF document
RELOAD